# Displaying product results in react using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi guys can anybody help me i was trying to navigate from searchform to this productResults page after the user input any text in the searchform.I am able to navigate to this page but I could not figure out why this component not working and showing any results upon arrival in this page.Any help would be appreciated.Basically I was trying to navigate to ProductResults component that would actually show results when user input something in SearchForm component.I am not sure where I went wrong.

```
SearchForm.js 

import React,{ useState} from "react";
import { Form, FormControl, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

 const  SearchForm = () => {
   const history = useHistory();
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

    const handleSearchInput = e => {
      setSearchTerm(e.target.value);

    };

    const handleSearchSubmit = () =>{

        if(searchTerm){
          let text = searchTerm;
          setSearchTerm({searchTerm: " "})
            history.push({
            pathname: "/productResults",
            state: { searchTerm: text}

          });


      }
      else {
        alert("Please enter some some search text!")

      }


    }

  return (
    <Form inline onSubmit= {handleSearchSubmit}>
                        <FormControl 
                            onChange={handleSearchInput}
                            value={searchTerm}
                            type="searchTerm"
                            placeholder="Search"
                            className="mr-sm-2"
                        />


                <button onClick={handleSearchSubmit} type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary">Search</button>

        </Form>
  );
  }
  export default SearchForm;


  ProductResults.js component responsible to display results

import React,{ useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { productList } from "./apiCore";
import Layout from './Layout';
import PCard from "./PCard";

 const  ProductResults =() => { 
        const[searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
        const [searchedResults, setSearchedResults] = useState([]);
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    handleSearch();

  });

    const handleSearch = () => {

      if(searchTerm){
        productList({ searchTerm: searchTerm || undefined})
        .then(response => {
            if(response.error){
              console.log(response.error);

            } else {

              setSearchTerm(searchTerm)
              setSearchedResults(response)
              console.log(response);
              setIsLoading(true)

            }

        })

      }

   }

     const searchedProducts = (searchedResults = []) => {
      return (
          <div className="row">
                  {searchedResults.map((product, i) => (
                      <div className="col-4 mb-3">
                          <PCard key={i} product={product} />
                      </div>
                  ))}
              </div>

      );
  };


    return (
      <Layout

            title="Searched Results "
            description="Search and find books of your choice"
            className="container-fluid"

            >
            <div className="row">
                {searchedProducts(searchedResults)}
            </div>

      </Layout>
    };
}
```

export default ProductResults;

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `this.setState` in function component

```
      this.setState ({
          isLoading: false,
          searchTerm: searchTerm,
          searchedResults: results

      });
```

Use instead

```
        setSearchTerm(searchTerm)
        setSearchedResults(results)
        setIsloading(false)
```

Comment: @Dipen What do you have in handleSearch in `results` variable?

Comment: thats where the problem is it is showing error something like TypeError: _apiCore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.productList.filter is not a function